# How to extract child groups from parent and re group using Linq

Tags: c#, list, linq, grouping

I have strange requirement. I am grouping records on the basis of certain criteria ( e.g Gln and other fields...) For each group I have further list of objects. I realized that few object from those list must be separated and need to replicate another group with the same Gln. Because, those objects should not be placed there. They must formulate another group with the same key ( i.e Gln ).

Please have a look on following code.

```
var claimsQuery = (from consignment in Consignments
                let consigneeAddress = consignment.ConsignmentAddresses.FirstOrDefault(pr => pr.AddressTypeId == 2)
                where (consignment.ClientId == 26 && consignment.FixDate != null )
                group consignment by new 
                {                                               
                    consigneeAddress.GLN,
                    consignment.ForwarderId,
                    consigneeAddress.Country.ISO,
                    consignment.FixDate,
                    ProductName = Products.FirstOrDefault(pr => pr.ProductId == consignment.ProductId).Name,
                    ProductId = consignment.ProductId
                }
                into g
                select new DepoOverviewData
                {

                    ForwarderId = g.Key.ForwarderId,
                    FixDate = g.Key.FixDate.GetValueOrDefault(),
                    Gln = g.Key.GLN,
                    ProductName = g.Key.ProductName,                                                

                    ConsignmentsOverviewData  = 
                            (from singleConsignment in Consignments.Where(pr => ( pr.FixDate == g.Key.FixDate)  && ( pr.ProductId ==  g.Key.ProductId))             
                             join x in ConsignmentAddresses on singleConsignment.ConsignmentId equals x.ConsignmentId
                             where x.GLN == g.Key.GLN && x.AddressTypeId == 2

                             select new ConsignmentClaimsOverviewData()
                             {                                          
                                    ConsignmentId = singleConsignment.ConsignmentId,
                                    Weight = singleConsignment.Weight,
                                    ChargeableWeight = singleConsignment.ChargeableWeight,
                                    TotalCost = singleConsignment.NetTotalCost,
                                    ProductId = singleConsignment.ProductId,
                                    ProductName = Products.FirstOrDefault(pr => pr.ProductId == singleConsignment.ProductId).Name,
                                    FixDate = singleConsignment.FixDate,
                                    ExpressTime = singleConsignment.ExpressTime, 
                                    ClientOrderNumber = singleConsignment.ClientOrderNumber,
                                    DeliveryDate = singleConsignment.DeliveryDate,   
                                    InTime = false, // this will be reset later. ( i.e True, false or null after iterating again over each group ).

                             }).ToList()
                }).ToList();
```

I also attached one image to demonstrate things.[image]

Comment: It will be much easier to help you if you create a smaller example of input and desired output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you fail to specify the criteria for when a group has to be split into two (or several), let me give you a generic example.

The idea behind it is to add another property to the grouping key that indicates the belonging to a "group in the group". I use `bool` to split groups into two, but of course this can be changed to a type having more than just two values.

If the input is like

```
var input = new[] {
    new { Key = 1, Value = 42 },
    new { Key = 1, Value = 101 },
    new { Key = 1, Value = 99 },
    new { Key = 2, Value = 999 },
    new { Key = 2, Value = 1001 },
    new { Key = 3, Value = 4711 }
};
```

and the rule for whether to create a separate group is

```
private static bool NeedsSeparateGroup(int key, int value)
{
    switch (key)
    {
        case 1: return value > 100;
        case 2: return value > 1000;
        default: return false;
    }
}
```

then just group also by what specifies the group-in-group belonging (don't like query syntax, but of course you can use it):

```
var result = input
    .GroupBy(raw => new
    {
        raw.Key,
        IsSeparateGroup = NeedsSeparateGroup(raw.Key, raw.Value)
    }, (k, vs) => new
    {
        k.Key,
        k.IsSeparateGroup,
        Values = vs.Select(r => r.Value).ToList()
    });
```

giving

```
Key: 1, IsSeparateGroup: False, Values: 42,99
Key: 1, IsSeparateGroup: True, Values: 101
Key: 2, IsSeparateGroup: False, Values: 999
Key: 2, IsSeparateGroup: True, Values: 1001
Key: 3, IsSeparateGroup: False, Values: 4711
```

Comment: thanks tinudu. it worked as you said. i really appreciate your help